# Axis2 SOAP Response element name camel case issue

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, axis

Please see the excerpt from my WSDL and SOAP response.

```
WSDL Definition:
----------------
<xs:complexType name="ContactInformation">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="AddressInfo"
            nillable="true" type="AddressInfo" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

SOAP Response:
--------------
<contactInformation>
    <addressInfo>
    </addressInfo>
</contactInformation>
```

Although in the WSDL the element name is "AddressInfo" (A is capital), the generated response is having the element name as "addressInfo". This is creating issue, as the existing consumer is using getElementsByTagName("AddressInfo") which is case sensitive, and I should not change the consumer code.

Please let me know what should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Axis2 supports different data bindings and there are several different ways to deploy a service in Axis2. You don't provide any details about how you generated/deployed your service and you even don't mention the Axis2 version that you are using. I don't think that anybody will be able to help you without that information.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the [obvious](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdX8y_xkz14), change "addressInfo" into "AddressInfo". Let us know if you need an XSLT stylesheet to do it.